Could you please explain why there are no matching values for the ggpairs axes?

So I just realized that the upper left y-axis does not match to any other variable/axis. The range of values for a is properly represented by the x-axis under a (bottom). What is the explanation? Thank you very much!
Cheers
I tried to look up the issue but did not find any answer so far :D

can you share code and data so others can help?

I think it is the probability density. That is, I think it's the same as the y-axis if you made a density plot of just the a variable.

Hi @Mike thank you for the hint. You can try the mtcars data set, it is basically the same
library(GGally)
p <- ggpairs(mtcars,
aes(color=factor(cyl),alpha = .4),
legend=1,
upper = "blank",
lower =
list(continuous =  "points" )
)
p
